# How to find correct pronunciations for Portugal-Portuguese words and phrases?

Tags: pronunciation, portuguese

I am going to Portugal soon to live for a couple of months and have a list of key phrases I think I'll be using a lot (a list of about 30 items). However I have been told that Google Translate only provides Brazilian Portuguese translations (which the Portugal Portuguese really hate) and that there is also a lot of words which are shared with Spanish (i.e. same spelling) but different pronunciations (which a lot of Portuguese also really don't like to hear). Is there any reliable way I can find the correct translations and pronunciations for a random list of Portuguese words? The words and phrases I'm looking for aren't necessarily the typical thing you'd find in phrase books, e.g. "scrambled eggs".

Answer (score 3):

There are several places where you can find the correct pronunciation of words, for example:

- The [Collins English-to-Portuguese Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-portuguese). If you search for a word, e.g. [guest](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-portuguese/guest), and scroll down to the section "guest in other languages", you will find pronunciations that you can listen to.
- One of the biggest online sources of pronunciations is Forvo, where you can find pronunciation files for many languages, including [Portuguese](https://forvo.com/languages/pt/). If you create an account, you can even download the pronunciation files (and then use them in your spaced repetition system).

However, Forvo also provides pronunciations of common phrases, e.g. [greetings and apologies](https://forvo.com/guides/useful_phrases_in_portuguese/greetings_and_apologies/), but if you are mainly interested in phrases, you can also try [Rhinospike](https://rhinospike.com/).

Answer (score 1):

WordReference provides a huge list of resources ([link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/resources-recursos.163358/#post-2691590)). Some of them are specifically listed as being for European Portuguese. You should go through them, but here are a couple that seem to be European Portuguese specific:

- [Dictionary](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/portugues-ingles/)
- [Verbs](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dlpo.aspx)