# Online Portuguese [PT-PT] language course

Tags: resource-request, portuguese

Duolingo has Portuguese in its program, but is built for [PT-BR], [Brazilian Portuguese](https://www.duolingo.com/course/pt/en/Learn-Portuguese). I’m looking for quite a while to find an online language course in European Portuguese [PT-PT].

In general, people will understand Brazilian Portuguese in Portugal, but it seems a bit odd to learn a language version which is quite different in pronunciation and vocabulary. At the end it seems that in Portugal Brazilian Portuguese is understood, but not really appreciated, since it is not the native language.

Is there a Portuguese online language course for learning European Portuguese?

Not directly related to this question, but covering a similar issue: [How to find correct pronunciations for Portugal-Portuguese words and phrases?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3596/how-to-find-correct-pronunciations-for-portugal-portuguese-words-and-phrases)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Since you tagged this question with [tag:duolingo], are you looking for a course hosted on that platform? If you are looking for a course hosted elsewhere, it would be better to remove that tag.

Comment: @Tsundoku Thanks for your comment, I've removed the tag

Comment: Unfortunately Duolingo only operates in  Brazilian Portuguese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for learning "European Portuguese", as it is sometimes called online, but they are not necessarily hosted on the best-known platforms. Below are a few that I have found:

- [Learn European Portuguese](https://www.practiceportuguese.com/) on PracticePortuguese.com.
- [European Portuguese Online Course | A1-B2 Levels](https://learn-portuguese.org/european-portuguese-online-course-2) by a certain Mia from Portugal, who has a Master's degree in teaching Portuguese to foreigners.
- [Learn European Portuguese](https://learneuropeanportuguese.pt/) by Daniela Pereira, who offers private classes online.
- [European Portuguese | Learn Continental Portuguese](https://europeanportuguese.com/), by a certain Nathan, who is not a native speaker.

In addition, there are guides to learning European Portuguese that provide some other useful pointers:

- [Guide to Learning Portuguese](https://www.portugal.com/travel/learn-portuguese/) on Portugal.com (December 2021).
- [How to Learn European Portuguese](https://www.portugalist.com/learn-portuguese/) on Portugalist.com.
- [Learning European Portuguese? Get Fluent with This Resource Guide!](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/portuguese/learn-european-portuguese/) on FluentU.com.
- [Learning European Portuguese: how to start the right way](https://turbolangs.com/en-gb/european-portuguese/) on Turbolangs.

Comment: thanks that is a very helpful list, which I've already forwarded to several friends, who want/need to learn European Portuguese

Answer (score -1):

I can teach you and prepare you for the exams, I built my online school to help people to speak our language with their family and friends.
The courses are very detailed and the 1–1 sessions are tailored to your needs.
https://www.letslearnportuguese.com/learn-portuguese-online/?swcfpc=1